# Symfony: Use distinct field for EntityType in a FormType form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

In my Symfony 3.4 project there's a contact us form that use a Symfony form Form/ContactType.php in which one of the dropdown boxes needs to the distinct values of an entity as the values that are displayed in that dropdown box.

Ex: ContactType.php form

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('type', EntityType::class, ['class'=>'AppBundle:Employees']);
    }
}
```

In this form there is a type field for which the employee types must be loaded. So the sql that needs to use for the above dropdown should be:

> SELECT distinct(e.type) AS type FROM AppBundle:Employees e

How can I load the result of this query in to this EntityType field in the Symfony form?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on query-builder for Entity form type.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder